# AbiWord saves files in native format only

Tags: release-juno

Unlike in many other Linux distros I know (Fedora, Manjaro...) AbiWord in  eOS only offers to save documents in its own native file format.

Anybody knows of a way to make AbiWord saving documents at least in rtf?

Thank you

Comment: Have you found anything about this? I wonder if its possible.

Comment: I believe its something to do with AbiWord, I hope someone will prove me wrong.

Comment: What I think to have understood is that Abiword import/export filters are (or may be) plugins someone forgot to add in the eOS repository release.